# Facebook requestCodes

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

I have an Activity that should handle results from both the Facebook SDK, and from other custom Activities.

Where can I find the requestCodes used by the Facebook SDK, in order to not use the same for my Activities?

I should be able to tell them apart in the `onActivityResult` using their requestCode so they need to be unique.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pass the request code in the `sdkInitialize` call

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context, 1200);
```

Then

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (FacebookSdk.isFacebookRequestCode(requestCode)) {
      //Facebook activity result
      //Do your stuff here
      //Further you can also check if it's login or Share etc by using 
      //CallbackManagerImpl as explained by rajath's answer here
      if (requestCode == CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()) {
          //login
      }
      else if (requestCode == CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Share.toRequestCode()){
         //share
      }
}
```

From [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookSdk/#isFacebookRequestCode)

> #### isFacebookRequestCode(int)
>
> Returns true if the request code is within the range used by Facebook SDK requests. This does not include request codes that you explicitly set on the dialogs, buttons or LoginManager. The range of request codes that the SDK uses starts at the callbackRequestCodeOffset and continues for the next 100 values.
>
> #### sdkInitialize(Context, int)
>
> This function initializes the Facebook SDK, the behavior of Facebook SDK functions are undetermined if this function is not called. It should be called as early as possible.
>
> **`public static synchronized void sdkInitialize(Context applicationContext, int callbackRequestCodeOffset)`**
>   **`applicationContext`**    The application context
>   **`callbackRequestCodeOffset`** The request code offset that Facebook activities will be called with. Please do not use the range between the value you set and another 100 entries after it in your other requests.

Answer (score 27):

Go to CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset. I personally used a piece of code like this to prevent unwanted behaviour.

```
if (requestCode == CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly.  It would be nice if this was more straightforward, it should be documented of course.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Log.iClassMethod();

    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                // do something ...
            }
            break;

        case ...:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                // do something ...
            }
            break;

        case Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE:
        {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.i("Facebook");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set your own request codes to disambiguate. All the OpenRequest and NewPermissionsRequest classes take a requestCode parameter:

[setRequestCode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/Session.OpenRequest/)

Answer (score 3):

Offering an alternative if you're using FB login via LoginButton

1. Set request code of login button
2. Use the request code to differentiate activity

---

```
private LoginButton mFacebookLoginButton;
private static int RC_FB_SIGN_IN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   mFacebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) findByViewId(R.id.fb_login_button);
   mFacebookLoginButton.registerCallback(...)
   RC_FB_SIGN_IN = mFacebookLoginButton.getRequestCode();
   ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_GP_SIGN_IN) {
        ...
    } else if (requestCode == RC_FB_SIGN_IN) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Doing my facebook usual things");
        mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Apetroaei Andrei's answer, there are other options available at Facebook SDK's [CallbackManagerImpl](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/CallbackManagerImpl.java) class:

```
public enum RequestCodeOffset {
    Login(0),
    Share(1),
    Message(2),
    Like(3),
    GameRequest(4),
    AppGroupCreate(5),
    AppGroupJoin(6),
    AppInvite(7),
    ;
```

These can be accessed by the foll. code:

```
if (requestCode == CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Share.toRequestCode()) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the lates sdk, (4.4.1), you can manually set the request code by modifying two files in the facebook library:
1) LoginClient.java

```
 public static int getLoginRequestCode() {
    //return CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode();
    return [your request code here];
}
```

2)LoginManager.java

```
 public void registerCallback(
     ...
    ((CallbackManagerImpl) callbackManager).registerCallback([your request code here],
            new CallbackManagerImpl.Callback() {
                @Override
            ...
            }
    );
}
```