# Android Facebook Login is not working

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am developing an Android app that uses Facebook login. This is my first Facebook login integration in Android. I am having a trouble with integrating facebook login to my app because nothing is shown login is success or not in my callback.

I generated Facebook hash key from debug sign key and set the credentials in Facebook developer settings as below.

[image]

In class name I set com.mmfashionnetwork.ptn.www.mmfashion.LoginActivity That is Login Activity where facebook login button and callback functions exist. My default activity is MainActivity. And facebook app is test mode.

This is my login activity and call back functions

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText tfEmail;
    private EditText tfPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
    private TextView tvForgetPassword;
    private TextView tvCreateAccount;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    private Config config;
    private LoginButton btnFbLogin;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        //other steps
        setUpFbLoginBtn();
    }

    private void setUpFbLoginBtn()
    {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I also set required credentials in Android manifest file. The problem is callback functions are not get called. As you can see I am toasting message in callback according to state. If I try to login clicking Facebook login button. I was redirect to Facebook as in screenshot.

[image]

When I click ok, no callback function is called. Current screenshot saying already authorized. But when I logged in for the first time, it is not showing any message when I was redirected to my app Login Activity as well. How can I retrieved data after logging in? In developer settings, I must set login activity class or main activity class? I tried setting both alternate. Both gave me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code for facebook login:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText tfEmail;
    private EditText tfPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
    private TextView tvForgetPassword;
    private TextView tvCreateAccount;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    private Config config;
    private LoginButton btnFbLogin;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setUpFbLoginBtn();
    }

    private void setUpFbLoginBtn() {

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to check facebook result in onActivityResult please?

Comment: @WaiYanHein you can doing it by setting your own `requestCode` .. for more detail visit this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772806/facebook-requestcodes